# Self-defined table template

Tags: tables, environments

When I write the template below, where:

- the first parameter has been designed for optional headers:
- the second has been designed to pass to tabularx.

I get the following error: *Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of @tempc. \end{extabularx}*

```
\newenvironment{extabularx}[2][]{%
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!25}{white}%
    \rownum=0%
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{#2}%
        \toprule%
        %\ifx\empty#1\relax\else(\rowcolor{gray!50} #1\tabularnewline)\fi%
        \ifthenelse{\empty#1}{%
            \relax
        }{%
            \rowcolor{gray!50}%
            #1\tabularnewline%
            \midrule%
        }%
}{%
        \bottomrule%
    \endtabularx%
}
```

Without IF statements it works fine, while with the \if or \ifx or \ifthenelse statements it doesn't work.

Comment: You're beginning an `\if` - statement in one table cell and try to finish it in another one, either by using `&` in `#1` or ultimately, when `\tabularnewline` is issued. This can't work, at least not this way

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, Exists another way?

Comment: Yes, Black TeX Magic ... with `\noalign` and constructing a token list containing the `\if....` test and then inserting the whole token list as first table row. There are examples of this here at TeX.SE

Comment: Latex is really complicated. With _C_ there are less problems :-)

Comment: Not if you try to do everything with preprocessor directives which would be closer to TeX processing than this strange language ;)

Comment: @BnG: C is no macro expansion language, apart from preprocessor statements

Comment: Yes, yes, I understand that. I've been going crazy with latex for a month, completely different from everything I knew.

Comment: If you want help with an error message then please always provide a small test file _that produces the error_  Then it is easy to debug. As it is it's rather hard to guess the usage,but  the test `\empty#1` looks very wrong but as you have not shown what you pass in as `#1` it is hard to suggest what it should be.

Comment: in particular `\empty` is defined by `\def\empty{}` so it does nothing at all. It seems a very odd thing to use in `\ifthenelse`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have provided no test file or example of how the command is used it is hard to help in detail but

```
%\ifx\empty#1\relax\else(\rowcolor{gray!50} #1\tabularnewline)\fi%
```

This is syntactically correct but tests if the first token in `#1` is the token `\empty`
if it is, that token is removed but remaining tokens of `#` are executed, followed by `\relax`.  If `#1` does not start with `\empty` then it typesets a `(` followed by `\rowcolor` which will always give an error as it has to be the first command in the row, but is following `(` here.

That was probably not the test intended (you mention it doesn't work but leave us to guess what you wanted it to do)

```
\ifthenelse{\empty#1}{%
    \relax
}{%
    \rowcolor{gray!50}%
    #1\tabularnewline%
    \midrule%
}%
```

`\ifthenelse` does not work via expansion so you do not want to use this here. the test clause with `\empty` is wrong but even if that were fixed, you would not be able to use `\rowcolor` or `\multicolumn` etc that need to be at the start of the row.

Possibly you want to replace all of the code I highlighted by

```
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
     \expandafter\@gobble
   \else
     \expandafter\@firstofone
    \fi
    {\rowcolor{gray!50} #1\tabularnewline\midrule}%
```

assuming `@` is a letter when you make the definitiuon (so in a package or after `\makeatletter` in the preamble)

That would use an expandable test to check if `#1` is empty, and use it to make a grey heading row if not empty.

Comment: No TeX Black Magic with `\noalign` here?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that is supplied by `\rowcolor`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have no words. It's incomprehensible, for now, but it works! The next step is to understand what this macro does and how using `\expandafter`. Thanks.